# Is there a prayer room in Frankfurt airport?

Tags: germany, fra, islam

Is there a prayer room facility in Frankfurt airport?

Some of us are desperate for this facilities as we sometimes route through this airport for umrah and Hajj

Comment: I'm kind of confused by both of these comments. I often visit UK airport prayer rooms (as I stress about all the people), and there's usually paraphernalia of various faiths, including a Qibla sticker, prayer mats, etc. Same sort of thing in hospitals. Is this rare worldwide? The idea of separate public prayer rooms for different faiths is new to me. Is it a cultural thing; something that's changing over time;...?

Comment: @DanSheppard I have seen mixed; sometimes same room is used by all faiths and sometimes they provide separate facilities.

Comment: @Sentinel  the answer is yes women can and do pray with men. There are certain conditions placed to ensure the integrity of men and women is maintained.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Yes.

The [Frankfurt Airport website page on Muslim prayer rooms](https://www.frankfurt-airport.com/en/flights-and-transfer/leisure-activities/muslim-prayer-rooms.html) says:

> Friday prayers are held in the Muslim prayer room in
> Terminal 1 every Friday at the time stated in the prayer calendar.
>
> Prayer room for Muslims
>
> - Terminal 1, Level 3, Departures B, Room 201.3014-3015
> - Terminal 1, Level 2, near Gate B22
> - Terminal 2, Level 3, near Gate D1
> - Terminal 2, Level 2, Arrival E

[There are also prayer rooms for other faiths.](https://www.frankfurt-airport.com/en/service-migration/prayers-and-mass-.html)

Answer (score 37):

Yes there is near gate B26. There are rooms for multiple faiths

It provides wudu area both for brothers and sisters

Comment: Why are you answering your own question?

Comment: @StrangerToKindness, answering your own question is accepted here, as it shares knowledge.

Comment: @StrangerToKindness there is a [help article on the topic](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: I am Allahmdulillah literally on the way from jeddah to mekkah now. This is something Inwas not aure about in frankfurt airport so posted this here immediately for everyone to benefit

Comment: @Cody I can't tell if you're joking, but *brothers and sisters* doesn't refer to biological siblings, but to fellow men or women respectively in the faith.  It's also used in Christianity.

Comment: Ah ok I see, so he should specify "brothers and sisters *within the Muslim faith*" as this site is visited by people from all belief and political systems

Comment: @YehudaSchwartz it's also a perfect question for this site.  Short and simple, with a short and simple answer, that is broadly useful to a significant number of people.  Most of the site's regular users will have seen the question within five hours and will have upvoted it at least for that reason.